# Virtual Hosting on my android device not working

Tags: android, remote-access, android-file, hosts, virtual-hosts

I am trying Virtual Hosting on my Android Device. For this I edited hosts file on following path: /system/etc/hosts as:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost
192.168.69.65           myserver.test.com
```

But this change is not working for me. Still when I am browsing myserver.test.com from browser, it is showing some random results and not hitting the actual server(i.e. 192.168.69.65).
On the other hand if I browse 192.168.69.65 directly it is working fine.
Please suggest something.

Regardss,
Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to put 1 empty line at end of file to make system to reload file like:

```
1.    127.0.0.1           localhost
2.    192.168.69.65           myserver.test.com
3.
```

No need to restart phone at all, i can ping new hostname immediatelly.
Thanks... :)

Comment: This worked for me. I'd been hitting my head against a wall wondering why it wasnt working all day! Thank you!!

Comment: try change 192.168.69.65 to 10.0.2.2